# Horizontal scrolling in item of vertical recyclerView in viewPager

Tags: android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have view pager.
In one of the fragment I have vertical recyclerView.
Each item in this recyclerView contains horizontal recyclerView.
It works fine, but when horizontal recyclerView scrolled to the end than view pager is scrolled to next page. But I want that view pager doesn't scrolled

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the ViewPager is scrolling is because, after the horizontal scroll is done scrolling, it transfers the rest of the scroll to the ViewPager. To stop the ViewPager from scrolling, use this extended ViewPager:

```
public class NonScrollingViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonScrollingViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollingViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```